# HYBRIS : Cronjob to assign product to a category?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to to create a cronjob that assigns newly created products to "New Arrivals" category.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a CronJob, consider using Prepare Interceptor to assign a category (assumed to be already existing) to a product. See: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/8bfbf43e8669101480d0f060d79b1baa.html